# Блокировка запроса на удаление

Tags: javascript, typescript, запрос, cors, redux-thunk

Не получается отправить запрос к бэкенду на удаление баннера на сайте. Причём только с ПК - с телефона запрос отправляется. Когда пытаюсь отправить запрос с ПК ругается CORS:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда бэкендер пытается с сайта отправить запрос на удаление баннера, у него вообще вылезает ошибка:

> net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Как решить эту проблему? Все остальные запросы к бэкенду (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) проходят нормально, как и должны. Бэкендер говорит, что у него CORS отключён.

Код запроса:

```
export const deleteBannerThunk = createAsyncThunk(
    'Delete banner',
    async (id: string) => {
        try {
            const response = await $api.delete(`/baners/${id}`);
            return id;
        } catch (err: any) {
            alert(err.response.data.message);
        }
    }
)
```